# creating thumbnailview for photo gallery in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am trying to create a photo gallery using Sencha Architect. On first screen I want to display image thumbnails displaying 4 images wide row.

Screen 2 will display a selected image, with name and image number ., say -3 of 10 at top.

I searched for a this on Google but not able to find any sample code or documention.
Is there any any sample code or doc available?

I need help in designing this code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some ideas from touchstyle example which comes with sencha touch library or have a look at this http://www.touchstyle.mobi/app/

Comment: Thank You Floyd for sharing this useful link,this will help me.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helped you. In case you need more help please ask.

Comment: touchstyle is good example but it is complex. Is there any simple way of creating thumbnail view?

Comment: If you are confused because of templates you can simply iterate over your data create each thumbnail as a panel with image in it and add all those panel to your main container

Comment: I created a thumbnail view for my photo gallery. I am able to populate the itemTpl of dataview through json. But I am not able to navigate between thumbnail view and full image view. Like when I tap or click on image that image should navigate to next view with full size and overlay - next prev for remaining images. Also toolbar should display image number for example 3 of 10